# Can I make a rule in security.yml that redirect me from login form to defined URI/patch only if I came from other defined URI/patch?

Tags: symfony

Can I make a rule in security.yml that redirect me from login form to defined URI/patch only if I came from other defined URI/patch ?

"If you come to login form from URI/path named **X** after authorization you will be redirected to URI/path named **Y** "

Comment: I don't think it is possible in security.yml. However you can define authenticationhandler and conditionally check referer path and reditrect user to desired route.

Answer (score 0):

In standard symfony edition, you can not configure this feature, but you can create a custom **success handler** (`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`) which will be called after complete authorization via form or another adapter and inject this handler to [configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) (`firewalls.form_login.success_handler`).

In own handler you can return the `RedirectResponse` for redirect user to another page.